# Is $H^{\frac{1}{2}}(\partial \Omega)\times H^{-\frac{1}{2}}(\partial \Omega)$ a Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

We have the operator $u \mapsto (u\vert_{\partial \Omega}, \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}\vert_{\partial \Omega})$, where $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ (Hilbert space), $\partial \Omega$ is the boundary $\Omega$, $n$ is the outward unit normal vector to $\partial \Omega$, and $\Delta u = 0$.

From "Functional Analysis, Haim Brezis", I know that $(u\vert_{\partial \Omega}, \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}\vert_{\partial \Omega}) \in H^{\frac{1}{2}}(\partial \Omega)\times H^{-\frac{1}{2}}(\partial \Omega)$.

Is $H^{\frac{1}{2}}(\partial \Omega)\times H^{-\frac{1}{2}}(\partial \Omega)$ a Hilbert space?

Comment: The book you are reading should give the definition of that space. What exactly is your question? Are you concerned that the space might not be complete?

Comment: I want to know why this space is a Hilbert space?

Comment: Ok, you just repeated your question. My point is, can´t you deduce this information from the book you are reading? If not, what exactly is your doubt?

Comment: Yes, I cannot deduce this (the proof of being Hilbert sapce) from the book. How can I prove that this space is a Hilbert space?

Comment: A Cartesian product of Hilbert spaces is again a Hilbert space (with the natural inner product). For the completeness one can argue analogously as for the completeness of $\mathbb C = \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$.